# How to show results of a function in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am a student learning JavaScript and I am trying to output the results of this function:

```
function randInt(lower, upper) {
   var size = randInt(1,10); 
   return Math.floor(lower + size*Math.random());
}
```

Here is the HTML I am trying to place the output in:

```
<h1>Random Tip<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
var tipNum = Math.floor(lower + size*Math.random());
document.write("<p>" +randInt(lower, uppers)+ "</p>");
</script>
```

I am totally screwing this one up!! Suggestions please!

Comment: Can you provide a test case? ([CodePen](http://codepen.io), [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), etc).

Comment: where do you want to display the output of your randInt function ? when is randInt called ?

Comment: You need to pass values here: `randInt(lower, uppers)` not use the names you named the arguments in the function.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I had no idea that tagging a question just Javascript meant you shouldn't include JQuery in the answer - you live and learn

So without jQuery - I think this does what you want (outputting a random number into an HTML element)

```
    <h1>Random Tip<br /></h1>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
      function randInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
      var randomNumber = randInt(10, 25);
      var target = document.getElementById('result');
      target.innerHTML = "<p>" + randomNumber + "</p>";
      });
    </script>
```

[updated Fiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/MqwTc/3/)

Comment: "Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function at some time when the page loads.

The below would certainly work:

```
   <html>
<head>
<script>
function randInt(lower, upper) {
   var size = upper - lower;
   return Math.floor(lower + size*Math.random());
}

function callOnLoad() {
var lower = 1;
var uppers = 10;
document.write("<p>" +randInt(lower, uppers)+ "</p>");
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="callOnLoad()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _The below would certainly work_. Please show me where you defined `lower, uppers`...

Comment: @gdoron thanks for pointing this out. Hopefully this works. :P

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like you are trying to generate a random number on each click .

try this

```
<h1 id='op' onclick="randInt(1,10)">Random Tip</h1><br />
  <script>
  function randInt(lower, upper) {
document.getElementById('op').innerHTML=(Math.floor(Math.random()*(upper-lower)));  //This will write the result in your heading tag.
    }
 </script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyUFuRo/1)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is recursion:

```
<script>
function randInt(lower, upper) {
    var size = randInt(1,10); 
    return Math.floor(lower + size*Math.random());       
}
</script>
```

Maybe are you looking for something like:

```
<script>
function randInt(lower, upper) {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
}
</script>

<h1>Random Tip<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // You cannot call randInt(lower, upper) without defining those variables
    document.write("<p>" +randInt(0, 10)+ "</p>");
</script>
```

Comment: bcoz randIn was calling randInt in turn.